# How do I read contents of a DataTable and assign them to other controls?

Tags: vb.net

**Good morning,**

I've been up all night trying to figure this out on my own without bugging anybody else, but I can't.

I've been successful in querying my MySQL database and gotten a set of records into a DataTable (dbTable).  During debugging, I can see its contents so I know the data is there.  Initially, the DataTable is used to populate a ListView control I have on my form.

When I select a record, I want the contents of the DataTable (or the query I just ran) to be assigned to some TextBox controls.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE TO ADD IMAGES:**
I'm hoping these screenshots will give an idea of what I'm looking to do.  The first image shows what happens after an account number has been entered.  The second box shows a Groupbox expanded to reveal the form fields after a record has been selected in the ListView.

**The control names are:** *TextBoxCustomer, TextBoxLastName, TextBoxFirstName, ComboBoxSalutation, ComboBoxCardType, TextBoxCard.Text, TextBoxExpireMonth, TextBoxExpireYear, TextBoxCVV2.*

**The field names in the DataTable (dbTable) are:**  nameCOMPANY, nameLAST, nameFIRST, nameSALUTATION, ccType, ccNumber, ccExpireMonth, ccExpireYear, ccCode.

IMAGE 1:
[image: After entry is made in TextBoxAccount.]

IMAGE 2:
[image: After a record is selected in the Listview]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
TextBox1.Text = dbTable.Rows(0)("ColumnName").ToString()
TextBox2.Text = dbTable.Rows(1)("OtherColumnName").ToString()
```

You can also do this:

```
Dim row as DataRow = dbTable.Rows(0)
TextBox1.Text = row("ColumnName").ToString()

row = dbTable.Rows(1)
TextBox2.Text = row("OtherColumnName").ToString()
```

You could also `DataBind` to a `DataGrid` (or similar control) using `dbTable` as the `DataSource` and then set the `DataGrid.EditMode` to `True`. This would create the textbox controls for you.

**UPDATE:**

Try something like this to bind your textboxes to the selected values of your ListView:

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim item As ListViewItem = Nothing
    Dim tb As TextBox = Nothing
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For Each item In ListView1.SelectedItems
        tb = Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & i.ToString, True)(0)
        If tb IsNot Nothing Then
            tb.Text = item.Text
        End If

        i += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

This is a little more error-proof, but this routine will only work if your textboxes are named `TextBox1`, `TextBox2`, `TextBox3`, etc.:

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim item As ListViewItem = Nothing
    Dim found() As Control = Nothing
    Dim tb As TextBox = Nothing
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For Each item In ListView1.SelectedItems
        found = Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & i.ToString, True)

        If found.Length > 0 Then
            tb = TryCast(found(0), TextBox)
        Else
            tb = Nothing
        End If

        If tb IsNot Nothing Then
            tb.Text = item.Text
        End If

        i += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Okay, thanks to the screenshots, I am assuming that your `ListView.MultiSelect = False`, so only one item can be selected at a time. Given that, the following should work as long as the textboxes and ListView columns are named correctly:

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim item As ListViewItem = Nothing
    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        item = ListView1.SelectedItems(0)

        txtCardNumber.Text = item.SubItems("CARD NUMBER")
        txtCardExpirationMonth.Text = item.SubItems("EXP MO")
        txtCardExpirationYear.Text = item.SubItems("EXP YEAR")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Pete, thanks.  I tried the first option you suggested and it worked.  But leaves another part of my problem unsolved.  Now that I have the info going to the textboxes, how do I tied that to the selection being made in the ListView?  The ListView is getting its data from the same DataTable (dbTable).

Comment: What do you mean by "tie" the textbox value to the ListView selection? What are you trying to do in your interface? Do you want the textbox values to change when an item is selected in the ListView (to the value of the selected item)?

Comment: Yes sir, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: WinForms.  My controls are on a GroupBox that's invisible until a selection is made in the ListView.  Then I make the groupbox visible - and the hope is to have the controls populated with the row of data that corresponds with the selection made.

Comment: I didn't work Pete, I got the following error:  _"Index was outside the bounds of the array."_

Comment: Thanks Pete, but it won't solve my problem since my textboxes don't follow a numerical sequence.  Also, I have other controls (like DateTimePicker, Combobox).  I'm fairly new to programming, but I'll look over you suggestions to see how I can adapt it to my situation.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Pete, I've edited my question to show screenshots of my Form.  Perhaps it might help illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks Pete - it didn't work as suggested.  But after a slight modification it worked.  Had to use the index number instead and add .text at the end of each line.  Unfortunately, this raised a new problem.  I just realized that even though my query is pulling data from two tables, I'm only displaying those 4 fields in the Listview.  As such, those are the only ones available to select and pass on to the form controls.

Comment: I believe there are two possible solutions: (1) Pull the info from the datatable (dbTable), or (2) Add all query results to the Listview and hide the horizontal scrollbar.  I prefer the latter, but don't know how to do it.  Care to help?

Comment: Sure, but start a new question please. This comment thread is getting too long (and it is a new problem, after all). I think the solution to the latter is going to be found by using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Hello guys/gals,**

With tremendous assistance from Pete, I was able to modify the suggested answer and I achieved the desired solution.  To prevent the horizontal scrollbars from displaying, I didn't add columns to the Listview (from the Designer).  Instead, I added the fields to the Listview programatically - this way they were available for selection.

The main trouble I ran into was figuring out the Index numbers of the fields.  I had to debug several times to figure out what the numbers were - so if anybody knows of a better way please do share.

**Here're the two codes I used (thanks Pete):**

```
    Private Sub loadCard()

    Try
        'FOR MySQL DATABASE USE
        Dim dbQuery As String = ""
        Dim dbCmd As New MySqlCommand
        Dim dbAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Dim dbTable As New DataTable
        Dim i As Integer

        If dbConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            dbConn.ConnectionString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};Uid={2};Password={3};Database=accounting", FormLogin.ComboBoxServerIP.SelectedItem, My.Settings.DB_Port, My.Settings.DB_UserID, My.Settings.DB_Password)
            dbConn.Open()
        End If

        dbQuery = "SELECT *" & _
                   "FROM cc_master INNER JOIN customer ON customer.accountNumber = cc_master.customer_accountNumber " & _
                   "WHERE customer.accountNumber = '" & TextBoxAccount.Text & "'"
        With dbCmd
            .CommandText = dbQuery
            .Connection = dbConn
        End With
        With dbAdapter
            .SelectCommand = dbCmd
            .Fill(dbTable)
        End With
        ListViewCard.Items.Clear()
        For i = 0 To dbTable.Rows.Count - 1
            With ListViewCard
                .Items.Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("ccID"))
                With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("ccNumber"))
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("ccExpireMonth"))
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("ccExpireYear"))
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("ccCode"))
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("ccType"))
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("ccAuthorizedUseStart"))
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("ccAuthorizedUseEnd"))
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("nameCOMPANY"))
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("nameSALUTATION"))
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("nameLAST"))
                    .Add(dbTable.Rows(i)("nameFIRST"))
                End With
            End With
        Next
        If dbTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            LabelNoCard.Visible = True
            LabelNoCard.Focus()
            TextBoxAccount.Focus()
            Me.Refresh()
        Else
            If dbTable.Rows.Count > 1 Then
                LabelNoCard.Visible = False
                LabelMultipleCards.Visible = True
                ListViewCard.Visible = True
                Me.Refresh()
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("A DATABASE ERROR HAS OCCURED" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & _
                    vbCrLf + "Please report this to the IT/Systems Helpdesk at Ext 131.")
    End Try
    dbConn.Close()
End Sub
```

Here's the second one:

```
    Private Sub ListViewCard_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListViewCard.SelectedIndexChanged

    GroupBox2.Visible = True
    Dim item As ListViewItem = Nothing
    If ListViewCard.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
        item = ListViewCard.SelectedItems(0)

        TextBoxCustomer.Text = item.SubItems(8).Text
        TextBoxLastName.Text = item.SubItems(10).Text
        TextBoxFirstName.Text = item.SubItems(11).Text
        ComboBoxSalutation.Text = item.SubItems(9).Text
        ComboBoxCardType.Text = item.SubItems(5).Text
        TextBoxCard.Text = item.SubItems(1).Text
        TextBoxExpireMonth.Text = item.SubItems(2).Text
        TextBoxExpireYear.Text = item.SubItems(3).Text
        TextBoxCVV2.Text = item.SubItems(4).Text
        DateTimePickerStartDate.Text = item.SubItems(6).Text
        DateTimePickerEndDate.Text = item.SubItems(7).Text

    End If
    End Sub
```